# Ecto Query - Preload one associated object for a number of records

Tags: database, elixir, ecto, preload

My app has a `Child` schema/model, that has many associated `ChildAttendance` records.

I can pretty easily preload all of the `child_attendances` for a given child:

`from ch in Child, preload: [:child_attendances]`

What I'd like to do is preload **only the last** attendance record for a given child, *or set of children*.

I tried the following:

```
  def with_last_attendance(query \\ Child) do
    last_attendance = from att in ChildAttendance,
                            order_by: [desc: att.in_at],
                            limit: 1
    from query, preload: [last_attendance: ^last_attendance]
  end
```

The above works, but only when the parent query is returning a single child (i.e. the `limit: 1` is limiting the number of attendance records being returned in total).

For example,

```
Repo.one!(Child |> where([ch], ch.id == ^child_id) |> with_last_attendance)
```

works as expected, with the child record containing a **single** `ChildAttendance` record loaded into the `last_attendance` association.

However, if the query is returning multiple children:

```
Repo.all(Child |> with_last_attendance)
```

only one of the returned `Child` records has the `last_attendance` association loaded (the `limit: 1` is "global" to the query).

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Comment: I think it would be nice to create a separate view for this thing on the database level and use it.

Answer (score 3):

From the discussion here https://elixirforum.com/t/ecto-and-preloading-most-recent-record-from-association/520, the following should solve your problem.

```
Repo.preload(
  Repo.all(Child), 
  child_attendances: from(ca in ChildAttendance, 
                       distinct: ca.child_id, 
                       order_by: [desc: ca.in_at]))
```